# Better merging in git mergetool?

Tags: git, merge, meld, mergetool

Is it possible to have **4** columns in mergetool/meld: Local, Base, Remote, Edited?
I.e. the same way it is now except you don't lose Base from sight when you are merging.

Answer (score 0):

Use `kdiff3` or `vimdiff` as a mergetool. Those show exactly the four versions.

Use

```
git mergetool -t kdiff3
```

to use it in this case or

```
git config --global merge.tool kdiff3
```

to use it as default.

Answer (score -1):

I am using meld for merges tools , Its is super cool for me , Try following.

1) sudo sudo apt-get install meld

2) Create file shall script file git-diff.sh on your desktop using vi editor

3) Add Following in this new created file, This is for run meld command

**#!/bin/bash

meld "$2" "$5" > /dev/null 2>&1**

4) Move this file and give rights

$ sudo mv git-diff.sh /usr/local/bin/

$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/git-diff.sh

5) Finally add in $HOME/.gitconfig to use this shall script

[diff]

```
    external = /usr/local/bin/git-diff.sh
```

6)  Edit any file and test this using changes in committed and current edited

```
git diff
```

7) if it work then on merging branch , if Conflict occur then try git mergetool that show you 3 file side by side , currentBranch file , Common ancestor file , target branch file